# Gitlab setup, rake fails because no --global user.name

Tags: nginx, gitolite

Following the 5.1 instructions to install gitlab

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md

When I run the command to test the install, I get an error "Git configured for user? ... no"

```
root@gitlab:/home/git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name  "GitLab"
  sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitlab@gitlab.ac"
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes
```

At no point in the instructions does it say to setup a user.name and user.email for the git user. 
Can I safely ignore this warning, or should I deviate from the instructions and set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should configure the name and email.

This will be incorporated into the documentation in a future release.

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/3894